# Unable to sort array of objects using Orderby Linq c#

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

Hi I am trying to sort an array of objects based on the value of a given field using Linq orderby command.

Here is my code:

```
LogDataPopulator[] arrLogPopulators = new LogDataPopulator[logCounter];
int counter = 0;
foreach (DateTime d in dtTimeVal)
{
    arrLogPopulators[counter] = new LogDataPopulator();
    arrLogPopulators[counter].messageDateTime = dtTimeVal[counter];
    arrLogPopulators[counter].messageContent = contentVal[counter];
    arrLogPopulators[counter].messagelevel = levelVal[counter];
    arrLogPopulators[counter].messagepublisher = publisherVal[counter];
    counter++;
}
LogDataPopulator[] sorted = new LogDataPopulator[logCounter];
sorted = arrLogPopulators.OrderBy(item => item.messageDateTime).ToArray();
```

I am however getting a null reference exception error

> System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
>   Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   Source=McLogViewer

Any idea how I should use the `OrderBy` clause and what I am doing wrong?

Any help would be much appreciated. Also I can sort the array of objects by casting it to a dictionary but that would not serve my purpose as I am trying to display the contents in a windows form gridview that is bound to the `LogDataPopulator` class.

Comment: Well what does the stack trace show? It's not at all clear that the problem is in the ordering... what's the type of `messageDateTime`?

Comment: It could be that the OrderBy is returning NULL and the exception is being thrown on the ToArray(); Remove the ToArray() and see if the exception still ocurrs.

Comment: Hi messageDateTime is of type DateTime

Comment: @CathalMF No. `OrderBy` will never return `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the length of `dtTimeVal` is equal to the length of `arrLogPopulators`. Otherwise you will end up with uninitialized members of `arrLogPopulators` which will throw a NullReferenceException when you attempt to sort on its `messageDateTime` property.

Answer (score 0):

It should work with something like this:

```
var sorted = (from d in dtTimeVal
    let arrLogPopulator = new LogDataPopulator(dtTimeVal[counter], contentVal[counter], 
                                  levelVal[counter], publisherVal[counter])
    orderby arrLogPopulator.messageDateTime
    select arrLogPopulator).ToArray()
```

With a constructor in your LogDataPopulator class:

```
public LogDataPopulator(//some arguments...)
{
    this.messageDateTime = //arg1;
    this.messageContent = //arg2;
    this.messagelevel = //arg3;
    this.messagepublisher = //arg4;
    //others arguments...
}
```